# How do you implement Libgdx touchDragged?

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm a beginner in Java and in Game Development too. I was following some tutorials, but now I'm stuck on implementing a touchDragged listener using libgdx,

Can anyone suggest how to drag the image when the user touches it and then move with the users finger position?

I am using both a stage and an actor. I want to catch a touchDragged event on an actor.

Thanks.

```
public void create () {
    Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false);

    stage = new Stage();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    // create a SpriteBatch with which to render the sprite
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    // load the sprite's texture. note: usually you have more than
    // one sprite in a texture, see {@see TextureAtlas} and {@see TextureRegion}.
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ball3.png"));
    Skin skin = new Skin();
    skin.add("default", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
    skin.add("ball", texture);
    Image sourceImage = new Image(skin, "ball");
    sourceImage.setBounds(50, 125, 100, 100);
    stage.addActor(sourceImage);

    // create an {@link OrthographicCamera} which is used to transform
    // touch coordinates to world coordinates.
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();

    // we want the camera to setup a viewport with pixels as units, with the
    // y-axis pointing upwards. The origin will be in the lower left corner
    // of the screen.
    camera.setToOrtho(false);
}

public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
    Table.drawDebug(stage);



    // if a finger is down, set the sprite's x/y coordinate.
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        // the unproject method takes a Vector3 in window coordinates (origin in
        // upper left corner, y-axis pointing down) and transforms it to world
        // coordinates.
        camera.unproject(spritePosition.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for your comment about unproject function :D,I suddenly found exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement [InputProcessor](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputEvent) where you can then handle the input.

Then in your main class in `create()` method you have to pass your `InputProcessor` to Gdx like this:

```
public void create() {
        float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(w,h);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new MyInputPocessor()); // THIS PART HERE
}
```

`InputProcessor` gives you `touchDragged(int x, int y, int pointer)` like this:

```
@Override
   public boolean touchDragged (int x, int y, int pointer) {
      // Move your image here.
      return false;
   }
```

also you can use other methods of `InputProcessor` like `touchDown()`, for example to check if user touched the image and not outside of it. And `touchUp()` for example to store the position when finger/mouse left the screen.

Comment: Close but since the OP is using a Stage and Actors he should pass his stage to the `setInputProcessor` method and on any Actor he could call `addListener` too add an `EventListener` subclass.